# What is the difference between getHibernateTemplate().update and getHibernateTemplate().merge

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on web project in which i want to update user into the database.
While writing code I found that it was giving an error if used as

> getHibernateTemplate().update(user) that "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions;"

But if I tried the same using `getHibernateTemplate().merge(user);` it perfectly worked fine.
What is the difference between those two ? And what exactly means by open session ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Merge** can work across sessions whereas **update** works only for the same session.

Although both are used for converting the object which is into its detached state to convert the object into its persisted state, but update will work only if we are in the same session, but merge will work even if its different session.

For more [info](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/difference-between-merge-and-update-methods-in-hibernate/).

By open session, it means that you are currently performing the operations in the same session (i.e. before closing the session)

Comment: Hey aditya thanks alot for your reply which clears my thought about merge and update

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you try to load same object again and again into the database in that case update and merge will come into the picture.

In update() if you modify the object before saving into the database then hibernate will throw an error because we can update the object in session only.

In merge(),opened session and the previous session will get merged together and object will get saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Both update() and merge() methods in hibernate are used to convert the object which is in detached state into persistence state.
see below code:

```
SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session1 = factory.openSession();

Student s1 = null;
Object o = session1.get(Student.class, new Integer(101));
s1 = (Student)o;
session1.close();

s1.setMarks(97);

Session session2 = factory.openSession();
Student s2 = null;
Object o1 = session2.get(Student.class, new Integer(101));
s2 = (Student)o1;
Transaction tx=session2.beginTransaction();

session2.merge(s1);
```

*Hear s1 is in detached state, now if we call update() method then hibernate will throws an error, because we can update the object in the session only

*So we opened another session [session2],  and again loaded the same student object from the database, but with name s2

*so in this session2, we called session2.merge(s1); now into s2 object s1 changes will be merged and saved into the database