# How to update detached entities?

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, transactions

I want to perform multiple updates on an `@Entity`. But based on some evaulations, I have to execute long running tasks in between. The task itself is based on a property of that entity. Thus, I first have to fetch the entity, merge some content, run the long task, and merge again.

This would span the database transaction, which is probably not correct:

```
@Transactional
public void update(DTO dto) {
    entity = findOne(dto.id);
    updateEntityFieldsFromDTO(entity, dto);

    if (entity.hasTaskCondition) {
        result = runLongTask(entity.property); //spanning the tx
        mergeResultIntoEntity(entity, result);
    }
}
```

Problem: the `runLongTask()` will block the transaction and keep the database connection open maybe for a long time, without interaction on the db.

Thus I thought creating single `@Transactional` methods, and running the task ouside of those tx:

```
//wrapper method without a transaction
public void updateFacade(DTO dto) {
    entity = service.update(dto.id);

    if (entity.hasTaskCondition) {
        //running outside the transaction
        result = runLongTask(entity.property);
        service.mergeResultIntoEntity(entity.id, result);
    }
}
```

Then my transactional methods would be as follows:

```
@Transactional
public Entity update(DTO dto) {
    //first select the entity
    entity = findOne(dto.id);

    //then merge the content
    updateEntityFieldsFromDTO(entity, dto);

    return entity;
}

@Transactional
public Entity mergeResultIntoEntity(id, result) {
    //again select the entity
    entity = findOne(dto.id);

    //now merge result into entity within tx

    return entity;
}
```

**Question**: is it correct to always pass the `entity.id` to the `@Transactional` methods, and then fetch the object from db *again* inside those tx methods?

I think I cannot pass the entity directly into the `@Transactional` methods from updateFacade, as the entity is `detached`. Correct?

Comment: I think `getHibernateTemplate().merge(entity)` is what you want. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20630271

Comment: Does `merge()` require to be running inside a transaction?

Comment: Yes, but the transcation can be different with the transaction of `findOne(dto.id)`.